# Difference between irange and counting_range in Boost

Tags: c++, boost, integer, range, counting

What's the difference between [`irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) and [`counting_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html)?

I needed `irange` to quickly generate a range of integers like this:

```
auto example = boost::irange(0, 5); /// result is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

But noticed an example somewhere (lost the link) that talks instead about `counting_range` to accomplish the same task. Is there a simple explanation of the difference between these two?

Comment: This has been an incredibly scarisome example of how misinformation can be presented as authoritative and peer-reviewed fact, on SO.

Answer (score 28):

The main difference is that [`irange`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) is a random-access range while [`counting_range`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html) isn't. `counting_range` is based on Boost.Iterator's [`counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) which uses all the underlying integers operations directly. Integers in C++ almost fit the iterator concept: the only thing missing is an `operator*`. `counting_iterator` provides an `operator*` as an identity operation and forwards everything else to the underlying type.

Another difference is that `irange` also supports increments different than 1.

None of them ever materialises the entire range of integers that they iterate over, so they both use O(1) memory.

Answer (score 1):

Both [`irange`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) and [`counting_range`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html) model a random access range for integer types. As `counting_range`s documentation points out, its iterator category is determined according to the following algorithm:

```
if (CategoryOrTraversal is not use_default)
    return CategoryOrTraversal
else if (numeric_limits<Incrementable>::is_specialized)
    return iterator-category(random_access_traversal_tag, Incrementable, const Incrementable&)
else
    return iterator-category(iterator_traversal<Incrementable>::type, Incrementable, const Incrementable&)
```

Therefore, for simple ranges such as `boost::irange(0, 10)` and `boost::counting_range(0, 10)` there is effectively no difference (aside from the types of each range, of course!).

However, `irange` also supports iteration with a different step size, e.g., `boost::irange(0, 10, 2)`, and `counting_range` also supports types that are only incrementable and do not fully model an integer.